# Accessing a shared property/variable in concurrent invocations of an AppleScript

Tags: applescript, concurrent-programming

This is my first time writing an applescript, and I want to accomplish a specific use case where multiple invocations of the same script are able to access and modify a specific global variable/property.

Take this dummy script for instance:

```
property counter : 0
set counter to counter + 1
delay 5
log counter
```

Say a second instance of this script is started 1 second after the first one. I want it to output `2` when it ends, instead of `1`

How can I accomplish such a use case? Would it be possible to use an environment variable created for this purpose?

(If I can help it would not like to read/write the value from a file)

Comment: The use of "property" saves the value in your script (new value is coded somewhere in your script itself). This property value is reset at the time you re-compile the script. So, if you do not recompile your script, your counter will keep increasing by each run as long as you not re-compile it. If you want to have this counter valide for 2 or more scripts, then you must record it somewhere in a separate file (text, plist, or any other format !) in a folder available for all your scripts (user library for instance). Then each script will read that file.

Answer (score 1):

Given your conditions, I'd recommend using UserDefaults. They can be accessed by simple shell commands:

```
defaults write [domain] [key] [value]

defaults read [domain] [key]
```

To execute shell scripts these in applescript, you would use:

```
do shell script "my_shell_code"
```

Here are some functions for a counter that you can use in your script:

```
on RegisterCounter()
try
do shell script "defaults read com.himanshu.my_timer_script counter"
on error
do shell script "defaults write com.himanshu.my_timer_script counter 0"
end try
end RegisterCounter

on IncrementCounter()
my RegisterCounter()
do shell script ("defaults write com.himanshu.my_timer_script counter " & (quoted form of (((my GetValueOfCounter()) + 1) as text)))
end IncrementCounter

on GetValueOfCounter()
my RegisterCounter()
return (do shell script "defaults read com.himanshu.my_timer_script counter") as integer
end GetValueOfCounter

on ResetCounter()
try
do shell script "defaults delete com.himanshu.my_timer_script counter"
my RegisterCounter()
end try
end ResetCounter
```

Paste these functions at the beginning or end of your script, and then call them using:

```
my FunctionName()
```

Comment: This seems it'll be the same as reading/writing to any file. Right? Do you think there's a way to accomplish this via reading/writing to a variable (i.e. in memory rather than a file)?

Comment: @Himanshu P While the variable is saved in a file, the file creation, management, and overwriting is all handled for you by the system. I think you'll have a lot of difficulties trying to pass variables to other instances of your script without writing variables to a file, even temporarily.